# Not opening gsheet by id when apk installed to a phone but emulator can open and edit the gsheet by its id

Tags: android, flutter, google-sheets, apk, google-sheets-api

I have gsheet credentials and Id. When I run the code through the emulator it works properly.
When installed as APK to couple of android phones;
This step worked properly;

```
final gsheet = GSheets(_credentials);
```

But this step is not working;

```
final ss = await gsheet.spreadsheet(_spreadsheetId);
```

I have used try/catch method and after the above steps the code does not execute.

I tried only this way.
I have allowed edits to the gsheet on all IP addresses but I need someone's help to fix this issue or I need a different way to achieve this.